# Querying xpath from another xpath query node

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

How do I query the node results of another xpath query in PHP?

Suppose I have the following XML:

```
<Orders>
      <Order>
        <OrderTotal>
          <Amount>15.45</Amount>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
        </OrderTotal>
        <ShippingAddress>
          <Name>John Doe</Name>
          <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
          <StateOrRegion>TX</StateOrRegion>
          <City>Austin</City>
        </ShippingAddress>
      </Order>
</Orders>
```

This doesn't seem to work:

```
foreach ($xo->xpath("//Orders/Order") as $o) {
    $order['total'] = $o->xpath('OrderTotal/Amount');
}
```

If I did the following then `total` would have a value, but I can't store an object chain like I can an xpath string:

```
foreach ($xo->xpath("//Orders/Order") as $o) {
    $order['total'] = (string)$o->OrderTotal->Amount;
}
```

Comment: Provide some example data

Comment: Added it to the post!

Comment: It works for me: `$order['total'][0] == '15.45';`

Comment: Having no luck. I just keep getting this: http://prntscr.com/3lfj4z

Comment: Put `echo $order['total'][0];` after the line where you assign it. If it doesn't work I suggest you share what PHP version you're using because it's working fine on mine (PHP 5.3.13)

Comment: Sorry, should have specified I'm using PHP 5.4. I just figured the problem out. If I change `$order['total'] = $o->xpath('OrderTotal/Amount');` to  `$order['total'] = (string)$o->xpath('OrderTotal/Amount')[0];` then it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` returns an array of SimpleXMLElement objects. You need to get the data from the first object in the list.

```
foreach ($xo->xpath("//Orders/Order") as $o) {
    $order['total'] = $o->xpath('OrderTotal/Amount')[0];
}
```

It is possible to use Xpath expressions to directly return a scalar value. The `string()` function casts the first element of a node list into a string for example. These expressions are not supported by SimpleXML, you would need to use DOMXpath::evaluate().

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate("//Orders/Order") as $node) {
    $order['total'] = $xpath->evaluate('string(OrderTotal/Amount)', $node);
}
```

Here is a small demo for the result handling: https://eval.in/155586